# Jenkins&Xcode : Build crashes in ipad frequently

Tags: xcode, jenkins, ipa

I'm currently generating an ios app with distribution profile. When I generate an ipa file from Xcode it works fine without any crashes when installed on an ipad but it crashes in most fields when generated from jenkins as a part CI process. Till now its working fine but the issue started while adding developed frameworks to the project. In jenkins I'm using below command line script for xcodebuild.
.   xcodebuild -workspace ~/.jenkins/jobs/workspace/repo/Source/App/App.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration "release" -sdk iphoneos VALID_ARCHS="armv64 armv7 armv7s i386" archive PROVISIONING_PROFILE="xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: company Limited" -archivePath ~/Desktop/../App.xcarchive

Unable to find out the exact issue for the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the environment variable of your jenkins node.. if they are overriding your build variables.

Before this can you provide more details.

Comment: No..there are no env.variables set for this project..everything is done in execute shell itself without using xcode plugin.

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with jenkins.. could be an issue with your developed frameworks